# add column in datatable with re-arranging number

Tags: c#, winforms

so, in here i want to add a unbound column to datatable that have been fill, in that datatable i got a column of custom number, and the number is random.
what i want is the new added columns was re-arranging the number from 1.

[image]

the code i use is

```
 public void SDB()
    {
        datatable dt = new datatable();
        dataset ds = new dataset();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, myConnection);
        try
        {
            ds.Tables.Clear();
            dt.Clear();
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandText = "Select code from gen order by code";
            myConnection.Open();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            gridControl1.DataSource = dt;               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));` then set desired values for the column.

Comment: what if i dont want to add a new data, but instead re-arrange the number at code(picture 8 until 65) to 1until 6

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++){ dt.Rows[i]["Code"] = i + 1; }`